# Is there a way to make a moving variable stop in processing through keyPressed

Tags: processing

I have an assignment, it expects a variable to be moved across the screen consistently, and bounce back once it reaches the end of the x-axis (I've done this part). But it also needs the variable to stop moving once a key is pressed... I understand I need to use keyPressed but I'm unsure of how to do it. Some friends told me to use a Boolean variable but I'm not entirely certain how to introduce it into the code.

Comment: An object can be moved by changing its coordinates stored in variables. A variable however, doesn't move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I have used the boolean variable `isMoving` to keep track of whether a key has been pressed or not. Then the position of the ball is only updated if this boolean value is true and if a key is pressed, the boolean value is updated.

```java
boolean isMoving = true;

// The position of the ball
int x = 500;
int y = 500;

// The speed of the ball
int x_inc = 2;
int y_inc = 3;

int diameter = 50;

void setup(){
  size(1000, 1000);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  
  if(isMoving){
    // Update ball position
    x += x_inc;
    y += y_inc;
    
    // Reverse direction for x axis
    if(x + diameter/2 >= width || x -diameter/2 <= 0){
        x_inc *= -1;
    }
  
    // Reverse direction for y axis
    if(y + diameter/2 >= height || y-diameter/2 <= 0){
        y_inc *= -1;
    }
  }
  
  circle(x, y, diameter);
}

void keyPressed(){
  // Update boolean value
  isMoving = !isMoving;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use a boolean variable is in an `if` statement. If you have a boolean variable `x`, you can write something like

```java
if (x) {
  //however you coded your ball's movement
}
```

And when `x` is true, the ball will move. When `x` is false, the ball won't move. After that, it's just a matter of changing `x` based on key presses.

Comment: So I'd make x false when key is pressed to stop it from moving ?

Comment: @CharlottePeterson I'm not super clear on what you're trying to do, but my suggestion is to experiment a little, and try different scenarios. If you're still having trouble, you can ask another question.

Comment: I ended up doing it, but now I have more questions which need answering lol. Is there a way we can PM ? I'd really like your help, and think it would be easier to explain if I showed my code and what's actually going on

Comment: @CharlottePeterson There isn't any built-in private messaging system on Stack Overflow, but if you want to show your code, you can edit your question and add it in there. If you would like to contact me separately, my email is in the following comment.

Comment: Hey! I emailed you :)